# Is there an R function to calculate UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as it does it in SQL?

Tags: r, uniqueidentifier

Is there an R function to calculate UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as it does it in SQL?

SQL code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, HASHBYTES('MD5', 'testing'))
```

outcome:
CA1F2BAE-5951-E549-D54F-B22B8ED95575

How could I get the same result in R?

Answer (score 0):

This function can help you

```
install.packages("uuid")
library("uuid")
UUIDgenerate()
```

Comment: The output I get using the following code:  UUIDgenerate("testing") , is "283fd5b2-4ccb-4e2f-ac0d-7eea2a395bac". But I need to get the same output as SQL that is CA1F2BAE-5951-E549-D54F-B22B8ED95575. I haven´t found how to do it.